# Using a parameter to make a new object in a method

Tags: java

If i miss any code please inform me and i will edit it.

So I have attempted this and done it this way:

I thought if the parameter is `(String albumTitle)` then I can assign the parameter to a variable `album = albumTitle;` .

Then create the new object `App album = new app();`.

Then add that object to the arrayList albums `albums.add(album)`.

I could be wrong but this is how I would do it.

full code here:

```
public void createAlbum(String albumTitle) {
        album = albumTitle;

        App album = new App ();
        albums.add(albumTitle);
        }
```

Comment: The code you shared will not even compile

Answer (score 2):

You've got things mixed up. You'd need to look into basics. Something like the following would do:

```
public class Main {

    static List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();

    class Album {
        String title;
        Album(String albumTitle) {
            title = albumTitle;
        }
    }

    public void createAlbum(String albumTitle) {
        Album album = new Album(albumTitle);
        albums.add(album);
    }
}
```